# Converter um string em numero

Tags: c#, conversão

Estou fazendo uma leitura em um arquivo excel, porém os valores dos mesmos estão vindo neste formato.

```
"-3,6379788070917E-12"
```

Código para conversão da string para decimal.

```cs
decimal.Parse(linha[5]);
```

Quando faço a conversão para decimal da erro, dizendo que o formato é inválido. Como consigo transformar este dado em numero?

Comment: Você pode garantir que esse número é sempre válido? De onde ele vem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar da seguinte maneira, mostrando que é um float:

```
decimal d = Decimal.Parse("1.2345E-02", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

Comment: Obrigado mzavarez deu certo.